# close the mobile menu when clicking on the menu link

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I need help with the mobile menu. I'm trying to find/add a script that closes the menu after clicking a menu link. Can anyone help?

Thus, when you click on a menu link, you access the section, but the menu is still open. So I need a script that it should menu after clicking menu link.

Here is my GitHub for this repository: https://github.com/Eric8306/Remparts

Thanks in advance for your help and your js script :)
[image: My menu html]I tried some scripts I found on the web but it doesn't work. I am in training as a developer and I have not yet seen javascript, hence my problem. So I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I understand, here is my GitHub for this repository : https://github.com/Eric8306/Remparts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below the code in your js file. Also include js library in head.

```
$(document).on("click",".header__nav .menu__list", function(){
   $(".header__Hamburger").trigger("click");
});
```

**Method 1:**

```
if ($(window).width() < 768){
   $(document).on("click",".header__nav .menu__list", function(){
     $(".header__Hamburger").trigger("click");
   });
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help... But this does not work:
The link ➡ https://eric8306.github.io/Remparts/
My github ➡ github.com/Eric8306/Remparts

Comment: `Also include js library in head.` jquery library not included.

Comment: Add this code in head `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Oh great it works fine, thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Hello, in fact, I just saw that the script applies another problem. Indeed now with this script in the desktop view it opens the menu in the same way in the mobile view. Other than that, that's not what I want. Can you help me fix this? thank you very much in advance

Comment: @EricL. Just check window width and add condition like `(if width <=767)`

Comment: Alright, I think I solved the problem. I did it this way, can you tell me if this is correct?
good for you

Comment: $(document).on("click",".header__checkbox:checked ~ .header__nav", function(){
  $(".header__Hamburger").trigger("click");
});

Comment: this class available only in mobile view. right?

Comment: This class, yes : .header__checkbox:checked ~ .header__nav

Comment: Then your code is fine.

Comment: but how use your methode(if width <=767) on your script. You can show me your script for that ?

Comment: Please check my answer. `Method 1`

Comment: like this, it does not work in mobile menu :                                      $(document).on("click",".header__nav .menu__list", function(){
  if width <=767
  $(".header__Hamburger").trigger("click");
});

Comment: Does not work too to with this method :                                                                    
        if ($(window).width() < 768){
   $(document).on("click",".header__nav .menu__list", function(){
     $(".header__Hamburger").trigger("click");
   });
}

Comment: but it works fine like this:
$(document).on("click", ".header__checkbox:checked ~ .header__nav", function () {
   $(".header__Hamburger").trigger("click");
});

Comment: Okay. Use that method.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre aide

Comment: Please type in English